# Angular: adding property in ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In `app.js`, i have added a **gem** object to represent one of the products in our **gemStore**. How can i assign it to the **product** property of **StoreController**.

```
(function(){
  var gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
  app.controller("StoreController",function($scope){

  });
})();
```

Comment: This is for the tutorial from the Angular website?

Answer (score 3):

You are better of using a gem factory:

```
angular.module('gemStore', []).
factory('GemFactory', [ function() {
   var gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };
   return gem;
   };
 ]);

angular.module('gemStore',[]).controller("StoreController",function($scope, GemFactory){
      $scope.product = GemFactory();
  });
```

This way you can just dependency inject it into any controller that requires your precious beautiful gems. plus you will have a gem factory which is bound to make you filthy rich in no time.

Comment: @NarasinghaPadhi Yes it works but it scales horribly. Try making another file and put your controller in that file. You avoid a global variable because you wrap your angular in a closjure (function(){})(). however in your other file var gem wil be undefined. just declaring a var outside of any angular scope is considered bad practice. define it either in a service, factory or controller

Comment: Okie. i will go with best practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assign the gem property to the scope object.

```
(function(){
  var gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
  app.controller("StoreController",function($scope){
      $scope.product = gem;
  });
})();
```

You would then output the properties of 'product' in StoreController's template.

```
<div>
    {{product.name}}
</div>
<div>
    {{product.price}}
</div>
```

You could put the gem in a service also so it's not just sat there in the closure.

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
  app.controller("StoreController",function($scope, GemSvc){
      $scope.product = GemSvc.getGem();
  });

  app.service("GemSvc",function(){
      var gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };

      this.getGem = function () {
          return gem;
      };
  });
})();
```

Then in your template, i've used the ng-controller method here as you did not state how you hook up your templates to controllers.

```
<div ng-controller="StoreController">
    {{product.name}}
    {{product.price}}
</div>
```

Comment: Then you have some error in your application logic that's not made clear from your question.

Answer (score 2):

You should maybe create it on the [controller scope](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp):

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

  app.controller("StoreController",function($scope) {
       $scope.gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };
  });
})();
```

It can now be displayed in your page with:

```
<div>Name: {{gem.name}}, Price: {{gem.price}}</div>
```

> Scope is an object that refers to the application model. It is an
>   execution context for expressions. Scopes are arranged in hierarchical
>   structure which mimic the DOM structure of the application. Scopes can
>   watch expressions and propagate events. - *[Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)*

Comment: Maybe adding more explanation about the controller scope, from the link, would be good?

Comment: @Pureferret Yep, good idea. I added the relevant part of the docs about scopes in Angular. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create a constant service in your app.js
You can put it into a real service also and access it
Example for constant service
Like following

```
(function(){
  var gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []).constant('GEM', {
    name: 'Azurite', 
    price: 2.95 
  });
  app.controller("StoreController",function($scope, GEM){
      $scope.product.name = GEM.name;
      $scope.product.price = GEM.price;
      //if you don't want to create a constant service then 
      //user directly like
      //$scope.product = gem;
  });
})();


<div>
    {{product.name}}
</div>
<div>
    {{product.price}}
</div>
```